# Got unsupported Scan error while scanning result of mysql query

Tags: mysql, go, time

I have a model in my project as below:

```
type MyModel struct {
    ID        int
    StartTime time.Time
    EndTime   time.Time
}
```

Which maps to a `mysql` table with this definition:

```
create table my_database.my_table
(
        id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
        start_time time,
        end_time time
)
```

This is the record inside the table:

```
insert into my_database.my_table values (1, '06:30', '18:00');
```

I have written an SQL query and tried to get the records with `database/sql` library:

```
query := `SELECT id, start_time, end_time FROM my_table`
rows, err := f.DBClient.Query(query)

defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    t := models.MyModel{}
    err = rows.Scan(
        &t.ID,
        &t.StartTime,
        &t.EndTime,
    )
```

I get the following error:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "start_time": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *time.Time
```

I changed my connection string and added `parseTime=true`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341590/how-to-parse-time-from-database

Comment: @jfarleyx, I actually find the `parseTime=true` solution from here; but it didn't work.

Comment: As that post states, that won't work for a time field. I was referring to the section about doing the custom parsing for time.

Comment: [This GitHub post](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/849) might be informative for why it doesn't work. I think you either need to switch to a `DATETIME` type, or use custom parsing as jfarleyx suggested.

Comment: Dear @jfarleyx, thanks for pointing out to the right section. I finally decided to have a custom parser, because other object types wouldn't match my business model. I think I'd better close my question, since it's a duplicate now.

Comment: @Jimeux, yes. I switched to a custom parser. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse time from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341590/how-to-parse-time-from-database)

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar Happy to help! Glad you found a solution.